# Are tags for what the content of the question is, or what the answer is?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, rollbacks

I was having some trouble with a recent question I asked and people kept editing in erroneous tags as I described the problem. I reverted back to the original over and over and finally I arrived at my answer. A visual studio feature was causing problems for me. I answered the question, but then someone came in and edited in the feature to the tags for the question.

But the question wasn't "Why is [feature] doing this?", it was "Why is this so slow?".

I'm frustrated in general with the response to my question so I don't know if I'm being obstinate, but I always considered tags to be tags about questions, not about answers.

So what was the right move here? Leave the tag that was described the answer, or rollback so that the tags represent the question?

Comment: @gnat I don't know about that one - doesn't cover the whole "answers" part.

Comment: @psubsee2003 this most means that answers part should be ignored when tagging (it's [meta-tag:faq] post). Or, more precisely that this faq would better be edited to cover answers part, if only by explicitly stating that it should be ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags exist for 2 reasons:

- Connect people with questions about topics that interest them.
- Connect people with answers to questions on topics they are looking for.

So if the tag will help someone interested in `x` find questions and answers about `x`, then the tag is appropriate.

So for your example, if the question is "Why is this so slow", and the answer is "because feature `x` was configured incorrectly", then the tag is correct because someone who is trying to find issues about `x` will be able to find your question more easily.

Comment: Sorry, I had mistakenly posted this to Meta Stack Exchange when I meant to post to Meta Stack Overflow. I found something there that had this same sentiment. Thank you.